# How do I prevent emoji from altering the height of a select tag?

Tags: html, css, emoji

I'm trying to show emoji in a `select` tag like this:

```html
<div>
  This is stuff <select>
<option>Something </option>
<option>Another thing</option>
</select>
</div>
```

The problem is, on macOS at least, that when I choose the emoji-containing option:

1. it makes the height of the whole containing component taller
2. AND the text within the select is shifted down (nearly cut off by the bottom of the select).

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dpgfa1ek/1/

And here is what it looks like (notice the shifting up and down):

[image]

How do I prevent all this shifting around?  Preferably, I'd like a CSS-only solution, but if I have to do JS, I can.

Comment: Make the height of the `select` as tall as the tallest option?

Comment: As a cynical non-emoji user, I must ask: do you *need* an emoji in there?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes, setting the height of the select to `1.6rem` does prevent the shifting: https://jsfiddle.net/c7wzw1oc/

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol The dropdown text is actually defined by the user, so if they want to put in emoji they can, but if they don't, they absolutely don't have to :)  I just want to handle it for those that do.

Comment: Well that's fair enough. Have you tried playing around with `vertical-align` CSS? It seems like the emoji is changing the height of the text, which affects the baseline position, which affects the alignment under default conditions. Try `vertical-align: bottom` perhaps.